# How to allow only group in regex

Tags: php, regex

I can't able to search this question

I want regex where i can allow a group of charcters So i want to allow charcters a to z and `&nbsp;` as a group i don't want to allow `&` and `;` alone but only as group

i tried

```
preg_replace('/[a-z(&nbsp;)]+/','string','replace');
```

but this is not working , can someone help

Comment: can u explain sir @anubhava

Comment: Link you provide here is very useful, thanks i can test it now @chris85

Comment: yes , it works for me u can move it to answer @chris85

Comment: hey chris can u tell me why here `&nbsp;` is not valid https://regex101.com/r/1FB2bJ/2,  if i remove & from first set than it is showing it valid

Comment: You added the `&` into the character class so the `&nbsp` is matched, the `;` is not in your character class though so it doesn't match. Invert the order so match the entity first and you will get all matches, https://regex101.com/r/1FB2bJ/3.

Comment: @chris85 get it , thanks

Comment: @chris85: the idea is here, but take care that `(a|b)+` isn't very well designed for a backtracking regex engine *(for each position the alternation must be tested, and backtracking regex engines are bad for this kind of tasks)*. The other way is to use unrolled patterns: `[a-z]+(?:&nbsp;[a-z]*)*|(?:&nbsp;[a-z]*)+` *(a bit long, but the alternation is tested only once.)*. Obviously, if you have to deal with short strings, it doesn't matter. *(I made a mistake in my previous comment <°)))))))>)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All characters in a character class are individual characters. So:

```
(&nbsp;)
```

is allowing

`(`, `&`, `n`, `b`,`s`,`p`,`;`

There are some exceptions to the  `all characters`; a range `a-z`, a leading `^` which inverts the usage, metacharacters `\n`... and probably a couple others.

you can use the character class and alteration to allow for the space entity.

```
([a-z]|&nbsp;)+
```

If you want to allow for more entities you can do more alterations on the entity side.

```
([a-z]|&(?:nbsp|deg|#160);)+
```

Here's a regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/1FB2bJ/1.